# How to get only not auto computed columns from a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have This query

```
SELECT  COLUMN_NAME 
FROM [INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS]
WHERE TABLE_NAME = @TableName 
      AND TABLE_SCHEMA = @TableSchema;
```

The thing is this query returns all the table's columns but what I want is to only return the not auto computed columns.
Any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [sys.columns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176106.aspx) instead, it has a column called `is_computed`

Answer (score 1):

INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS does not have that information. You can use sys.columns

```
select  *
from    sys.columns
where   object_id   = object_id('table_name')
and     is_computed = 0
```